# Why am I receiving a null object reference?

Tags: android, sql, null

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop feature to a RecylcerView that's populated by an SQL. I'm currently trying to swap the positions of 2x list elements by calling the following methods:

I am calling a log and have confirmed the fromPosition and toPosition variables are correct; so ***why am I receiving this error of null object reference in the LogCat, and how do I solve it to not be null?***

### ListAdapter:

```
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Log.d(TAG, fromPosition + "");
        Log.d(TAG, toPosition + "");
        dbHelper.updateOrder(fromPosition, toPosition);
        dbHelper.updateOrder(toPosition, fromPosition);


        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return true;
    }
```

### DBHelper:

```
public void updateOrder(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(SORT_ID, toPosition);
        db.update(TABLE_USERdETAIL, cv, "_id="+fromPosition, null);
    }
```

### LogCat Error Message:

```
Process: mackinnoninc.packmule, PID: 17423
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void mackinnoninc.packmule.DbHelper.updateOrder(long, int)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at mackinnoninc.packmule.ListAdapter.onItemMove(ListAdapter.java:102)
                                                                           at mackinnoninc.packmule.SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.onMove(SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.java:34)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper.moveIfNecessary(ItemTouchHelper.java:852)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper.access$100(ItemTouchHelper.java:76)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper$2.onTouchEvent(ItemTouchHelper.java:376)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnItemTouch(RecyclerView.java:2464)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2607)
                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9303)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2775)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9523)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4242)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4108)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3799)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3856)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5969)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5869)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6072)
                                                                           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
                                                                           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:183)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.j
```

Comment: dbHelper object is null.

Comment: yep, thank you, can you put your comment as an answer so I can mark this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `dbHelper` object is null. You should initialize it first.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't initialize DbHelper. Somewhere in constructor initialize it with 
`private DbHelper dbHelper;`
`dbHelper = new DbHelper();`

Answer (score 0):

I can not proof this in Your given code. But because the ErrorStackTrace i'd say the dbHelper Object is uninitialized when You call it in onItemMove(). You should check if dbHelper is null when calling it.